# Is it possible to install multiple apps in android mobile device?

Tags: android, string, installation

I have a requirement to install multiple android apps of same functionality in android mobile. Basically if we change the app name in the "strings.xml" we can install the application with that name in the device (here Sample Project is the app name)

```
<string name="app_name">Sample Project</string>
```

if here i want to change the app name to "sample" then when i install it replaces with "Sample Project" 
My requirement is to install the apps with different names but without replacing them. so to achieve this what i should do i don't have any idea about it. please help me to find out the solution

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the identifier of an android application is it's package name. So you can install same app with different package name in one device. So to achieve your goal you need to change the application package name

in eclipse to change an application package name do the following

> right click on project name > android tools > rename application
>   package > new package name

Comment: yeah i got it thanks for your answer but is there any way to do it without changing the package name

Comment: you can not install two app with same package name... the later one will replace the first one

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have checked it on my device. I have one more doubt, if u have any idea please clarify it. If am generating 2 apk for same project whether google allows to keep it in play store???

Comment: same things there.. if you use different package name then you can upload same project.. but if you use same then it will just update if the version is higher

Comment: also - In the androidManifest.xml. Make sure that every <provider> has an android:authorities with a different names then the original app.